# How to place a string value to a tkinter text box? String value comes from another function

Tags: python, string, tkinter, stringstream

```
def selection_changed(self,event):
    global change_val     
    selection = self.TCombobox1.get()
    get_sel_val = selection.split('=')
    cur_sel_val = get_sel_val[1]
    get_cur_val = selection.partition('=')[0] # Returns string 
    get_cur_val
    #print(cur_sel_val)
    change_val = get_cur_val
    #Configuring the text in Label widget   
    def update_text():  
        self.Label1_2.configure(text=cur_sel_val)
    update_text()                                              
    messagebox.showinfo(
        title="New Selection",       
        message=f"Selected option: {get_cur_val}")

    self.Label1_2 = tk.Label(self.Frame1_1)
    self.Label1_2.place(relx=0.179, rely=0.519, 
    relheight=0.326,relwidth=0.613)
    self.Label1_2.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
    self.Label1_2.configure(borderwidth="5")
    self.Label1_2.configure(compound='center')
    self.Label1_2.configure(font="-family {DejaVu Sans} -size 10")
    self.Label1_2.configure(relief="groove")
    self.Label1_2.configure(text = get_new_val)
```

Comment: `widget['text'] = something` would work on a Label or a Button, but a Text behaves rather differently - you need to use methods like `.insert()` on it to add text.  (You know this already, you used exactly that technique to give it its initial text!)  Note that you will need to temporarily set the Text's `state` back to "normal" in order to be able to modify it, setting it to "disabled" prevents ANY changes.

Comment: The text widget has a documented `insert` method, and you are using it successfully in one place. Have you tried using it in the other place?

Comment: You already know how to *insert text into the `Text` widget* but you do not insert `get_cur_var` into it.  Also why do you create new text widget whenever selection changed?  Should `self.Text1` already be created once outside the function?

Comment: Thanks for the reply's my problem is getting the dynamic value get_cur_value into the text widget. I can't seem to figure out how to write that line of code. I have tried self.Text1['text'] = get_cur_val without sucess  error is... name 'get_cur_val' is not defined can't seem to be able to get the list /string get_cur_val out of the function definition even though both are under the same toplevel tk definition. Reason for new creation is this is connected to combobox with mutiple selections

Comment: As said, your code has the line `self.Text1.insert(END,'hi from text box')` that insert text into `self.Text1`, so I wonder why you cannot insert the content of `get_cur_val` into `self.Text1`.

Comment: Finally figured it out!! print(type(var)) is your friend also sub functions Thanks for all the help